# configuring kafka + minio on minikube

Tags: apache-kafka, minikube, minio

I would like to run the [minio resize](https://github.com/kubeless/functions/tree/master/incubator/minio-resize) function  on my minikube (v0.28.0). 
I installed kubekess (v0.6.0) and deployed kafka using the yaml file provided with this version (kafka-zookeeper-v0.6.0.yaml).

I installed minio following [these steps](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/minio/minio/master/docs/orchestration/minikube/README.md).
I also mc and enabled kafka in the .minio/config.json 
every thing seem deployed correctly.

```
$ kubectl get services
  NAME           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
  broker         ClusterIP   None             <none>        9092/TCP            2d
  kafka          ClusterIP   10.98.179.36     <none>        9092/TCP            2d
  kubernetes     ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP             6d
  minio          ClusterIP   None             <none>        9000/TCP            3d
  minio-public   ClusterIP   10.101.140.13    <none>        9000/TCP            3d
  zoo            ClusterIP   None             <none>        9092/TCP,3888/TCP   2d
  zookeeper      ClusterIP   10.107.189.185   <none>        2181/TCP            2d
$ kubectl get pods
  NAME                     READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
  hello-696b7f4964-894d5   1/1       Running   2          4d
  kafka-0                  1/1       Running   3          2d
  minio-0                  1/1       Running   1          3d
  minio-1                  1/1       Running   1          3d
  minio-2                  1/1       Running   1          3d
  minio-3                  1/1       Running   1          3d
  zoo-0                    1/1       Running   1          2d
$ kubectl get deployments
  NAME                       DESIRED   CURRENT   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
  kafka-trigger-controller   1         0         0            0           2d
```

however I'm not able to add events to my local minio. here is the error.

```
$ mc events add localminio/foobar arn:minio:sqs:us-east-1:1:kafka --events put
 mc: <ERROR> Cannot enable notification on the specified bucket. A specified destination ARN does not exist or is not well-formed. Verify the destination ARN.
```

Answer (score 0):

@user1027336 The ARN seems to be correct. The only time you will get this error is if either the kafka section in config.json is not set properly or kafka is not setup properly. I found https://linuxhint.com/install-apache-kafka-ubuntu/ very helpful in installing `kafka` on a Ubuntu machine. As far as the config.json is concerned,

This is what i have

`"kafka": {
            "1": {
                "enable": true,
                "brokers": ["localhost:9092"],
                "topic": "testing"
            }
        },`

https://blog.minio.io/part-6-6-publish-minio-events-via-kafka-83aa606ffb65 gives a good description on how to enable kafka with minio